# Logger function fails in Golang

Tags: go

I have what should be a very simple logger function but while the log file is created, nothing is written to it.  I tried several different things but it continues to fail.  The function is

```
func logger(logname string, message string) {
    logName := "../planner/log/" + logname + ".log"
    var file *os.File

    file, err := os.OpenFile(logName, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("File", logName, "failed with error:", err)
    }

    //file.WriteString(message)
    fmt.Fprintf(file, message)
    fmt.Println("Wrote", message, "to", logName)
    file.Sync()
    file.Close()

    test, err := os.Stat(logName)
    size := test.Size()
    fmt.Println("File size is", size)
}
```

Comment: Yes: stop ignoring errors from all the functions dealing with that file after opening it. They all return errors, and `fmt.Fprintf` is no exception.

Comment: Not using the [`log` package](https://golang.org/pkg/log/).

Comment: Thanks, Kostix.  I'm slow responding because I've been tending my wounded ego, but you're correct, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting anything in file because you are not opening it with `os.WRONLY`  or `os.RDWR`. By default. `os.OpenFile` returns a buffer with only read permission. You might want to close your file with a `defer`  in  case the code panics with `defer file.Close()`.